# Who are these people that hang out with candy bars?

Tags: wordplay

> Plain Diamonds
>   Doobie Fair Lady
>   Host Mallet
>   Mr Mallard
>   Sprint Defense Escher
>   Large Not Large
>   Binary Shackles
>   Infantry Man Child
>   Miss Nervous
>   Half Byte

Comment: Does the trivia tag apply here? I imagine that the answers will be dependent on your geography; not all candy bar brands are available in all parts of the world.

Comment: In fact, the brand of candy bar that they hang out with is of no consequence and the reference to candy bars serves merely to stimulate a hint as to what kind of people these may be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Partial answer:**

> Each phrase clues a different hip hop artist. A line of poetry in hip hop is called a *bar*, and you might call a particularly sweet line a *candy bar*. (OP revealed in comments that *candy bar* was supposed to clue *rapper*, from *wrapper*).

Plain Diamonds

> **VANILLA ICE** (due to Personman), although **JUST-ICE** (suggested by M Oehm) also fits.

Doobie Fair Lady

> **JAY Z** (J + Nissan Fairlady Z—revealed by OP)

Host Mallet

> **MC HAMMER**

Mr Mallard

> **DRAKE** (a male bird—revealed by OP) (My original guess was **BIRDMAN**.)

Sprint Defense Escher

> **RUN-D.M.C.** (RUN + D + M.C.)

Large Not Large

> **BIGGIE SMALLS**

Binary Shackles

> **2 CHAINZ**

Infantry Man Child

> **SOULJA BOY**

Miss Nervous

> Possibly **NELLY** (suggested by Duncan), from the expression *nervous Nellie*. This clue seems more indirect than the others, and I am not sure the function of *miss*.

Half Byte

> **50 CENT** (This clue plays on the ambiguity of *bit*. A bit is 12.5 cents as well as a unit of data in computing, eight of which constitute a byte—confirmed by OP.)

Comment: Well on the way! Mr Mallard requires a person with more specificity to the clue.

Comment: Plain Diamonds is Just Ice.

Comment: I had a different one in mind for Plain Diamonds, but I'll give half-credit for the fact that it fits.

Comment: Vanilla Ice, presumably.

Comment: Best wrapper alive!

Comment: Miss Nervous = Nelly (Nervous Nellie)

Comment: It seems we've been informed that the "with candy bars" clue is actually about the "wrapper" pun, not the more complex explanation given in this answer :)

Comment: I refused to correct it because it sounded way cooler than my lame pun.

Comment: To clarify: Doobie Fair Lady = Jay-Z (you needed to get the Nissan Fairlady Z car). Mr. Mallard = Drake (a male duck). Half Byte = 50 Cent (4 bits = 50 cents, 2 bits = 1 quarter). Otherwise, great job!